# Application of Fubini's theorem in economic theory

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-distributions

The economy is populated by a continuum of infinitely-lived consumers and producers, distributed uniformly on the unit interval $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$, and a finite number of miners. Time is discrete; $t = 0, 1, 2, ..., \infty$ and each time period is divided into two subperiods; labelled *day* and *night*.

Let $x_{t}(i)\in\mathbb{R}$ denote the consumption (production, if negative) of the perishable good in the day at date $t$. Let $x_{t}(j)\in\mathbb{R_{+}}$ denote miner $j$'s consumption of the day good. All agents want to consume the day good.

Because this day good is perishable, can I say that there is an aggregate resource constraint given by *Fubini-Tonelli theorem* show below?
\begin{align}
\iint x_{t}(i,j)\mathrm di\mathrm dj \leq 0 
\end{align}

for all $t \geq 0$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$ in the limit.

Also, can  $E_{0}x_{t}(i,j)=0$ hold if I say that agents experience a stochastic shock?

If these conditions do not hold then what assumptions can I make to ensure that they hold mathematically?

Comment: What is $x_t(i,j)$?

Comment: It's like a joint distribution function of $x_{t}(i)$ and $x_{t}(j)$.

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. You seem to be using $x_t$ as the name of three different functions (one when you write $x_t(i)$, another when you write $x_t(j)$, and a third when you write $x_t(i,j)$).

Comment: They just mean $x_{t}^{i}$, $x_{t}^{j}$, and so on.